# How to show data from object in snakbar in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a snakbar which gets notification from Web Service and displays information whether Job Execution was successful or failure.

Code to parse Json:

```
    this.messageService.messageReceived$.subscribe(data => {

        this.snakbar.statusBar("Platform job Completed - " + data, "Info");
        let webService: WebService = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(webService.message);
        console.log(webService.executionId);
        console.log(webService.code);
        this.spinner.hide();
        this.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

I have created an Interface to parse Json

```
interface WebService {
jobId: string,
executionId: string,
code: number,
message: string,
data: string
}
```

Using console.log I am able to view data in console.However I want to show message in snakbar.
Right now I am getting `'Platform job Completed - [Object][Object]'`
I want something like this in snakbar `'Platform job Completed - Success/Failure Info"'`

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

First Assign the subscribed value to some variable.

```
this.data = data;
```

Then, try to get the message value from data as shown below.

```
this.snakbar.statusBar("Platform job Completed - " + this.data.message, "Info");
```

Complete Code

```
const project = JSON.parse(this.dataService.getObject("project"));
    if (project != null) {
        this.globalAppSateService.onMessage(project);
        this.project = project;
    }
    this.messageService.messageReceived$.subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data; // assigning data to reuse
        this.snakbar.statusBar("Platform job Completed - " + this.data.message, "Info");
        let webService: WebService = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(webService.message);
        console.log(webService.executionId);
        console.log(webService.code);
        this.spinner.hide();
        this.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

Comment: I am getting error Property data doesn't exist on type MetaData.component.ts

Comment: are you getting the response inside subscribe? just put  console.log(this.data) after assigning the data and check you have received the response or not.

Comment: Please consider using [_template literals_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to simplify the concatenation of strings. (In this case, it should be `\`Platform job completed - ${this.data.message} Info\``)